# Dose flurry sdk support by apple store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, flurry-analytics

i am new to implement flurry analytics, i want to implement flurry Crash analytics SDK in my iOS application,for generate the crash report of my application, my question is 'dose apple support flurry Crash Analytics SDK, or it may reject by apple at the time of app store submission'. if anyone know then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes apple support flurry analytics and also approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Chetan,
Apple will approve flurry sdks and will not reject by them.
I have already uploaded 2-3 apps which contains this sdk especially for this purpose which you mentioned here.
So feel free to upload your application.